# Laravel - Laravel Deployment failed on DigitalOcean

Tags: laravel, sudo

I deployed my Laravel-5.8 to Digital Ocean.

/etc/nginx/sites-available/default

```html
server {
 listen 80 default_server;
 listen [::]:80 default_server;

 # SSL configuration
 #
 # listen 443 ssl default_server;
 # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
 #
 # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
 # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
 #
 # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
 # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
 #
 # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
 # Don't use them in a production server!
 #
 # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

 root /var/www/html/peopleedge;

 # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        # index index.php index.html index.htm;
 # index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

 server_name 123.130.32.49;

 location / {
  # First attempt to serve request as file, then
  # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
  # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
 }

 # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
 #
 location ~ \.php$ {
  include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
 #
 # # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
  fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
 # # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
 # fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
 }

 # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
 # concurs with nginx's one
 #
 location ~ /\.ht {
  deny all;
 }
}
```

When I tried to open the site, I got this error:

[image: digitalocean error]

Secondly, my am I seeing htdocs on my online server since I deployed to DigitalOcean:

> There is no existing directory at "C:\xampp\htdocs\peopleedge\storage\logs" and its not buildable: Permission denied

I run all these commands, but the problems still persists:

```
sudo chgrp -R www-data storage bootstrap/cache 
sudo chmod -R ug+rwx storage bootstrap/cache
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/html/peopleedge
sudo chmod -R o+w /var/www/html/peopleedge/storage/
```

How do I resolve it?

Thank you

Comment: `php artisan route:clear`

`php artisan config:clear`

`php artisan cache:clear` please clear the cache

Comment: Check if `logs` folder exists in `/var/www/html/peopleedge/storage/` directory. If not then create it with sudo permissions.